# How do I watch youtube on my TV using a netbook or media computer?

Tags: internet, tv, youtube

I'm based in the UK. I'd like to watch iplayer, 4od, youtube etc on my TV. I've looked at the Roku box, but as far as I can gather this doesn't support youtube or 4od. I don't have cable in my area and don't want to go with Sky.

What options do I have, if any?

**UPDATE**

My TV has an HDMI connection.

If a netbook is the best or only way to do this, which one would you recommend for connecting to my TV?

Comment: Please clarify that you want to use a computer to do this, otherwise I'm betting it gets closed as off topic.

Comment: A netbook perhaps? I would also class a Roku box as a computer.

Comment: But... will the community?  Stay tuned for this and more exciting drama on Superuser.com!

Comment: Well the Roku box runs a computer O/S i.e Linux.

Answer (score 1):

Many new LCD TVs have VGA inputs these days.  If your netbook happens to have an HDMI output, you could use that.  Connecting the netbook to the TV directly is the easiest way.  You can run a media center type software such as XBMC if you want a "TV-friendly" interface.

If you use VGA, you'll have to connect your netbook's sound (the audio output jack) to a separate stereo or powered speakers.

If your netbook only has a VGA output, and your TV only has S-Video in or other analog video input, you need to purchase a converter.  You need an active converter in this case (something like [this](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000S675JU) will not work, I believe it's for a desktop graphics card that is re-using the VGA pins as an analog video output.)

Comment: Thanks for the info about XBMC I'd not come across it. Is a netbook the only option? Is there any Roku box equivalent that supports youtube in the UK? If this is not the correct forum for such a question can you point me to one that is? Ideally a stack exchange type one.

Answer (score 0):

There are some boxes which support Youtube, I've been using boxee box (manufactured by d-link)  which has a modded version of xbmc, a full html5 compliant browser and a youtube app. The downside is that it costs about USD 200.

Comment: Many thanks. The Boxee looks like it provides more of what I'm looking for than the Roku.